# Wijmo Dialog Feature visible problems

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm trying to make these certain fields invisible but they are still showing up. Any ideas?

```
$(".successMessage").wijdialog({
            pin: { visible: false },
            refresh: { visible: false },
            toggle: { visible: false },
            minimize: { visible: false },
            maximize: { visible: false },
            width: 400,
            height: 110

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

captionButtons is an option set, you would need to define it like this:

```
$(".successMessage").wijdialog({
            captionButtons: {
                pin: { visible: false },
                refresh: { visible: false },
                toggle: { visible: false },
                minimize: { visible: false },
                maximize: { visible: false }
            },
            width: 400,
            height: 110
});
```